# How to wait until processes finish Java AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to wait until my processes finish before I return my speechlet response, otherwise it seems to cut my process off and thus, not complete it, I actually believe it may freeze the process, but thats not my desire.

How do I go about waiting?

```
@Override
public SpeechletResponse onIntent(SpeechletRequestEnvelope<IntentRequest> requestEnvelope) {
    IntentRequest request = requestEnvelope.getRequest();

    Intent intent = request.getIntent();
    String intentName = (intent != null) ? intent.getName() : null;

    if (intentName == null) return null;

    switch (intentName) {
        case IntentTitle.NEW_TICKET:

            switch (request.getDialogState()) {
                case STARTED:
                    return Response.getDialogueResponse(intent, true);
                case IN_PROGRESS:
                    return Response.getDialogueResponse(intent, false);
                case COMPLETED:
                    String numberString = intent.getSlot(SlotTitle.ID).getValue();
                    if (!NumberUtils.isCreatable(numberString)) return Response.ERROR;

                    Member member = Info.GUILD.getMemberById(numberString);
                    User sender = UserDB.getUser(member);

                    CommissionTicket commissionTicket = new CommissionTicket(sender);
                    commissionTicket.create();

                    //wait until processes finish before continuing

                    return Response.NEW_TICKED_CREATED;
            }
    }

    return null;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Had a look at the CloudWatch logs, and well, pretty much what I expected was happening is happening... have a look at the times for these logs (I ran them 3 different times, so 3 different times are logged, but apart of the same lambda session)

```
public void create() {
    System.out.println("log2");
    GuildController guildController = Info.GUILD.getController();

    guildController.createTextChannel(ticketType.name().toLowerCase() + "-" + creator.getName() + "-" + id.value()).queue(channel -> {
        System.out.println("log3");
                ChannelManager channelManager = channel.getManager();
                GuildManager guildManager = channelManager.getGuild().getManager();
                List<Member> members = guildManager.getGuild().getMembers();
                List<Member> admins = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Member member : members) {
                    for (Role role : member.getRoles()) {
                        if (!role.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(Info.ADMIN_STRING)) continue;
                        admins.add(member);
                    }
                }
        System.out.println("log4");
                for (Member member : members) {
                    if (member.equals(creator.getMember())) continue;
                    channel.createPermissionOverride(member).setDeny(Permission.MESSAGE_READ).queue();
                }
        System.out.println("log5");

                for (Member admin : admins) {
                    if (admin.equals(creator.getMember())) continue;
                    channel.createPermissionOverride(admin).setAllow(Permission.MESSAGE_READ).queue();
                }
        System.out.println("log6");

                BotMessage botMessage = new BotMessage();
                botMessage
                        .setTitle("New Ticket! User: " + creator.getName())
                        .setColour(Color.CYAN)
                        .setDescription("Please enter your full request here! \n" +
                                "Make sure to let us know whether you are looking for a quote/timeframe,\n" +
                                "or have a budget in mind, and we will work around you!\n\n" +
                                "A sales representative will be with you as soon as possible!")
                        .send((TextChannel) channel);
        System.out.println("log7");

                this.textChannel = (TextChannel) channel;

                TicketDB.addTicket(this);
        System.out.println("log8");
            }
    );
```

Logs:

https://gyazo.com/0ad2baa8d1438be8364dd1112159c4f4
https://gyazo.com/e197f33335046afe3c9f8f1ace267d30

**UPDATE**
Implemented the Future class, worked, but still a bit buggy.
It now completely creates the ticket, which is great, however, when I go to send the same call again, it for some reason sends a message in the same channel before preceding to create the next ticket.

So, to simulate...

Function call through AWS Lambda

Creates ticket completely

Function call through AWS Lambda again

Sends a message or two in the previous tickets channel

Creates new ticket completely

https://gyazo.com/dc6e4391f4964f41a73f1c3be92190f9

```
@Override
public SpeechletResponse onIntent(SpeechletRequestEnvelope<IntentRequest> requestEnvelope) {
    IntentRequest request = requestEnvelope.getRequest();

    Intent intent = request.getIntent();
    String intentName = (intent != null) ? intent.getName() : null;

    if (intentName == null) return null;

    switch (intentName) {
        case IntentTitle.NEW_TICKET:

            switch (request.getDialogState()) {
                case STARTED:
                    return Response.getDialogueResponse(intent, true);
                case IN_PROGRESS:
                    return Response.getDialogueResponse(intent, false);
                case COMPLETED:
                    String numberString = intent.getSlot(SlotTitle.ID).getValue();
                    if (!NumberUtils.isCreatable(numberString)) return Response.ERROR;

                    Member member = Info.GUILD.getMemberById(numberString);
                    User sender = UserDB.getUser(member);

                    System.out.println("log1");

                    Future<Ticket> commissionTicket = new CommissionTicket(sender).create();
                    try {
                        commissionTicket.get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //wait until processes finish before continuing

                    return Response.NEW_TICKED_CREATED;
            }
    }

    return null;
}
```

In the Ticket class:

```
public Future<Ticket> create() {
    System.out.println("log2");
    GuildController guildController = Info.GUILD.getController();
    RequestFuture<Channel> channelRequestFuture = guildController.createTextChannel(ticketType.name().toLowerCase() + "-" + creator.getName() + "-" + id.value()).submit();
    try {
        Channel channel = channelRequestFuture.get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    System.out.println("log3");
        ChannelManager channelManager = channel.getManager();
        GuildManager guildManager = channelManager.getGuild().getManager();
        List<Member> members = guildManager.getGuild().getMembers();
        List<Member> admins = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Member member : members) {
            for (Role role : member.getRoles()) {
                if (!role.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(Info.ADMIN_STRING)) continue;
                admins.add(member);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("log4");
        for (Member member : members) {
            if (member.equals(creator.getMember())) continue;
            channel.createPermissionOverride(member).setDeny(Permission.MESSAGE_READ).queue();
        }
        System.out.println("log5");

        for (Member admin : admins) {
            if (admin.equals(creator.getMember())) continue;
            channel.createPermissionOverride(admin).setAllow(Permission.MESSAGE_READ).queue();
        }
        System.out.println("log6");

        BotMessage botMessage = new BotMessage();
        botMessage
                .setTitle("New Ticket! User: " + creator.getName())
                .setColour(Color.CYAN)
                .setDescription("Please enter your full request here! \n" +
                        "Make sure to let us know whether you are looking for a quote/timeframe,\n" +
                        "or have a budget in mind, and we will work around you!\n\n" +
                        "A sales representative will be with you as soon as possible!")
                .send((TextChannel) channel);
        System.out.println("log7");

        this.textChannel = (TextChannel) channel;

        TicketDB.addTicket(this);
        System.out.println("log8");
        Future<Ticket> future = ConcurrentUtils.constantFuture(this);
        return future;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (!userIsInTicket(creator)) users.add(creator);
    return null;

}
```

Comment: Hows is AWS Lamda involved here?  What part of your code involves it?

Comment: I recommend to use `AWS Step Functions` to do that. https://console.aws.amazon.com/states/home?region=us-east-1#/homepage

Comment: Well, the speechlet response part of it, thats with the Alexa Skills Kit, which is ran through aws lambda, as well as the Intent part of it. Also, dont really understand aws step functions, how would they help here?

Comment: Also, the issue with AWS Lambda is that it is a stateless, run as you need type of function. So, the code opens, executes, then closes, with no trace (unless youve saved state somewhere in a database or the likes), but if it closes early, such as in the example above where it returns Response.NEW_TICKET_CREATED, then the code is frozen and not executed completely, which isnt what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on inside `commissionTicket.create();` (I assume it's your code, not part of some library, and that it's running asynchronously somehow), but one solution would be to have that method return a `Future<>` object and then wait on it to finish. Something along the lines of:

```java
Future<CommissionTicket> commissionTicketFuture = CommissionTicket.create(sender);
commissionTicketFuture.get(SOME_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLIS);
return Response.NEW_TICKET_CREATED;
```

Comment: So does this actually make sure the code is finished before continuing with the rest of the code? I will test it soon when I get home.

Comment: Also, the code isnt running asynchronously, it is ran on the same thread, but the execution seems to halt after I send that last bit of code

Comment: It looks like the `queue()` method you are calling in your edit above submits a task asynchronously. You're just supplying a success callback function that will execute when the asynchronous thread finishes executing. Lambda is returning immediately after `queue()`, because the executing thread immediately returns from `create()`. I believe the library you are using is [this one](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/blob/master/src/main/java/net/dv8tion/jda/core/requests/RestAction.java). It looks like if you call `submit()` instead of `queue()`, you can get a `Future<>` back and wait on it.

Comment: So, that worked, thanks alot for that, I updated the post though, as for some reason the messages send twice after I recall the same lambda function. Any reason why this can be happening? It should never send that message in the same channel more than once, and doesnt when I normally execute the code in a non-lambda environment.

Comment: Nevermind, for some reason that no longer happens. Magically fixed itself. Thanks alot for the help :)

Comment: Nevermind didnt magically fix itself... my best guess is that the lambda function stays 'warm', and somehow that recalls the same function again? Any guess on how to go about fixing this